# SQLite - reverse string function

Tags: sqlite

Is there a function for reversing string in SQLite? I'm unable to find anything in the documentation.

Comment: I think you might have to write your own extension for this. Can you tell us why you need to reverse a string in SQL? There might be a better way to get there.

Comment: I just wanted to do a one time job in SQLite. I can program it in PHP or any other language. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no builtin function for that. You can add custom function, like in this example in Python:

```python
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("")

conn.create_function("strrev", 1, lambda s: s[::-1])

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(r''' SELECT strrev('hello, world') ''')
print(cur.fetchone()[0]) #dlrow ,olleh
```

Answer (score 11):

Using a common table expression it is possible to reverse a string in SQLite.

```
WITH reverse(i, c) AS (
    values(-1, '')
    UNION ALL SELECT i-1, substr('dlrow olleh', i, 1) AS r FROM reverse
    WHERE r!=''
) SELECT group_concat(c, '') AS reversed FROM reverse;
```

Returns `hello world`.

Comment: This seems to be a great solution, but the input string isn't variable. How to adapt this solution to work with arbitrary input?

Comment: @tohuwawohu what exactly is the input?

Comment: A simple text value (sorry, "arbitrary input" wasn't precise). I simply don't know how to use the CTE in connection with a simple SELECT statement. I suppose i have to replace the "group_concat(c, '')" clause?

Comment: replace the string in substr

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem storing word reverses which I obtained via this PHP script:

```php
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
        function __construct()
        {
                $dbFile = __DIR__ . '/Dictionary.sqlite';
                $this->open($dbFile);
        }            
}

$db = new MyDB();

$db->createFunction('rev', 'strrev', 1);
$db->exec('UPDATE dict_en SET word_rev = rev(word)');

echo "done";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello MartyIX**,

Yes, Sqlite3 has a function you can use to reverse strings.

## Reverse Strings in Sqlite

### Conditions

1. You have to know the length of the string.
2. If you want to reverse all strings in a column, all strings **must** be of equal length.

### Example

Imagine you got a table named *myTable* like this one.

```
_id |   myField
--------------------
1   |   08641944
2   |   08950407
3   |   00250898
4   |   00498293
5   |   04502851
6   |   03146310
7   |   03146310
8   |   03146310
9   |   03146310
```

In this case the column *myField* contains strings of 8 characters in length.

#### Query

```
SELECT myField,
    SUBSTR(myField,-1,1)||
    SUBSTR(myField,-2,1)||
    SUBSTR(myField,-3,1)||
    SUBSTR(myField,-4,1)||
    SUBSTR(myField,-5,1)||
    SUBSTR(myField,-6,1)||
    SUBSTR(myField,-7,1)||
    SUBSTR(myField,-8,1) 'reversed' 
FROM myTable;
```

#### Result

```
myField     |    reversed
-------------------------
08641944    |    44914680
08950407    |    70405980
00250898    |    89805200
00498293    |    39289400
04502851    |    15820540
03146310    |    01364130
03146310    |    01364130
03146310    |    01364130
03146310    |    01364130
```

### Explanation

The *negative integer*, e.g. **-1** in SUBSTR(myField,**-1**,1),
tells Sqlite to start at the rightmost character in the string.

The *positive integer*, e.g. **1** in SUBSTR(myField,-1,**1**),
tells Sqlite to pick just one character.

The `||`, in e.g. SUBSTR(myField,-1,1)`||`,
invokes the **group_concat(X)** function.

The **'reversed'**, in SUBSTR(myField,-8,1) **'reversed'**,
tells Sqlite to put the reversed strings in a new column labeled **reversed**.

The *SELECT* statement above would normally be put inside
a *CREATE VIEW AS* statement.

### Example

#### CREATE VIEW AS

```
CREATE VIEW reversed AS
    SELECT myField,
        SUBSTR(myField,-1,1)||
        SUBSTR(myField,-2,1)||
        SUBSTR(myField,-3,1)||
        SUBSTR(myField,-4,1)||
        SUBSTR(myField,-5,1)||
        SUBSTR(myField,-6,1)||
        SUBSTR(myField,-7,1)||
        SUBSTR(myField,-8,1) 'reversed' 
    FROM myTable;
```

### Update

If the string is 1000 characters long, as [hamstergene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544621/hamstergene) points out, you will have to use your scripting language to create a function that do the two following operations.

1. Query the field to get string length.
2. Create the SELECT statement programmatically based on the count.

Perhaps [hamstergene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544621/hamstergene) could help you with that.

Comment: And if the strings are 1000 characters long, I think your colleagues will start submitting to The Daily WTF even before you're finished typing the query :)

Comment: @LarsB: Yes, I can do that this way but my strings are not fixed length. I really appreciate the time you spent writing the answer but unfortunately it won't help me in my task.

Answer (score -3):

As others have already explained, SUBSTR with a negative first parameter returns inverted text. This could be used with LENGTH to not depend on knowing the actual length of the field. So:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(myfield , -LENGTH (myfield), LENGTH (myfield)) as inverted_myfield FROM [...]
```

This will return *myfield* but with inverted String (*inverted_myfield*).

Comment: I would be nice but is just does not work