# sqlite full text wild card search

Tags: sqlite

Can Sqlite FT3 or FT4 do something like

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE body MATCH '*qlite'
```

I know this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE body MATCH 'Sqlite*'
```

works but seems like `'%like'` like operation doesn't work in the full text.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are asking the query to return rows if there are any words than end in qlite in the contents of the body column?

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand it's a limitation of FTS in general, across platforms, that suffix/postfix searches aren't possible.

The best workaround I've seen is to add a column to MyTable called ReverseBody and store the reverse of the Body column in there and add it to the FT index as well.  Then you write queries like

select * from MyTable where reversebody match (REVERSE('qlite') + '*')

I work in SQL Server so we have a REVERSE built in. I don't think SQLite does, but you can add custom functions to do it as descrbed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836271/358858)

Comment: Main issue with this strategy is that wildcards in the middle of a phrase also won't be found. E.g., "*name*" in "firstnames".