# Sqlite 3 sorting for arabic and persian names?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am currently using sqlite 3 in my project and i would like to know if there is any sorting method to handle arabic and persian names as i understand that these languages are read from right to left. 
Sorting i meant is like the way we arrange english names by alphabetic order ,similarly i want to arrange the arabic/persian names in some order(similar to alphabetic for english)
If there is any sqlite call which is supported by sqlite 3 to arrange by looking up the last character first rather than the first character?

regards

Maddy

Comment: You could reverse the text and then sort on it. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826876/sqlite-reverse-string-function and combine it with `ORDER` clause.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function to handle this.

You can define your own collation with [sqlite3_create_collation*()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from tbl 
order by case 
        when name like 'آ%' then 0
        when name like 'ا%' then 1
        when name like 'ب%' then 2
        when name like 'پ%' then 3
        when name like 'ت%' then 4
        when name like 'ث%' then 5
        when name like 'ج%' then 6
        when name like 'چ%' then 7
        when name like 'ح%' then 8
        when name like 'خ%' then 9
        when name like 'د%' then 10
        when name like 'ذ%' then 11
        when name like 'ر%' then 12
        when name like 'ز%' then 13
        when name like 'ژ%' then 14
        when name like 'س%' then 15
        when name like 'ش%' then 16
        when name like 'ص%' then 17
        when name like 'ض%' then 18
        when name like 'ط%' then 19
        when name like 'ظ%' then 20
        when name like 'ع%' then 21
        when name like 'غ%' then 22
        when name like 'ف%' then 23
        when name like 'ق%' then 24
        when name like 'ک%' then 25
        when name like 'گ%' then 26
        when name like 'ل%' then 27
        when name like 'م%' then 28
        when name like 'ن%' then 29
        when name like 'و%' then 30
        when name like 'ه%' then 31
        when name like 'ی%' then 32
        when name like 'ي%' then 33
        else 34
        end asc,name asc;
```