# SQL check if fields contains same letters

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to check if there is a row in my table that contains the same letters but in different order, but it must have the exact same letters, no more and no less.

For example, I have the letters "abc":

```
bca -> true

acb -> true

abcd -> **false**

ab -> **false**
```

Thanks!

Comment: SQLite doesn't have a `reverse` like function. See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826876/sqlite-reverse-string-function

Comment: Would this work? CASE WHEN yourfield like ('%a%') and yourfield like ('%b%') and yourfield like ('%c%') and LEN(yourfield) = 3  THEN 'True' ELSE 'False'

Comment: Is this a one time thing? is Python an option?

Comment: What about bcca and abc?

Comment: sqlite version?

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive `CTE`s to split the parameter `'abc'` and each column value to letters and compare them:

```
with
  recursive paramletters as (
    select 'abc' col, 1 pos, substr('abc', 1, 1) letter
    union all
    select col, pos + 1, substr(col, pos + 1, 1)
    from paramletters
    where pos < length(col)      
  ),  
  param as (
    select group_concat(letter, '') over (order by letter) paramvalue
    from paramletters
    order by paramvalue desc limit 1
  ),  
  cteletters as (
    select col, 1 pos, substr(col, 1, 1) letter
    from tablename
    union all
    select col, pos + 1, substr(col, pos + 1, 1)
    from cteletters
    where pos < length(col)
   ),
  cte as (
    select * from ( 
      select col, group_concat(letter, '') over (partition by col order by letter) colvalue
      from cteletters
    )
    where length(colvalue) = length(col)
   )  
select c.col, c.colvalue = p.paramvalue result 
from cte c cross join param p
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cvFpHd5XwEzUdVogA4eLvT/0).
Results:

```
| col  | result |
| ---- | ------ |
| ab   | 0      |
| abcd | 0      |
| acb  | 1      |
| bca  | 1      |
```

If the letters of the parameter are already sorted (like `'abc'`) then this code can be simplified to use only the last 2 `CTE`s.