# Reverse a text column in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Given a `text` column in SQLite, how can I reverse its values?

For example, given this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "testwords" ("word" text);
INSERT INTO "testwords"("word") VALUES ('Hello'), ('world!'), ('foo bar baz');
```

which `SELECT` statements give `'olleH'`, `'!dlrow'`, `'zab rab oof'`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLite - reverse string function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826876/sqlite-reverse-string-function)

Comment: I don't think so. The answers there (while technically answering that question) use non-SQL code, apply only to one string constant (but what's the point), or fix a (small) upper length limit in advance.
Should I post my answer there, and abandon this question?

Answer (score 2):

You can do so with a **recursive CTE** (which is a bit involved for such a simple task):

```sql
-- Create and populate example table:
CREATE TABLE "testwords" ("word" text);
INSERT INTO "testwords"("word") VALUES ('Hello'), ('world!'), ('foo bar baz');

-- CTE to select the reversed characters from the "testwords" table:
WITH RECURSIVE "reverse" ("stringno", "string", "charno", "char") AS (

    SELECT -- start at the last character:
        _rowid_
    ,   "word"
    ,   length("word")
    ,   substr("word", -1, 1)
    FROM "testwords"
    
    UNION ALL

    SELECT -- recurse: move one letter to the left
        "stringno"
    ,   "string"
    ,   "charno" - 1
    ,   substr("string", "charno" - 1, 1)
    FROM "reverse"
    WHERE "charno" > 1 -- stop condition
)
SELECT
    "string"
,   group_concat("char", '') AS "reversed"
FROM "reverse"
GROUP BY "stringno";
```

The recursive CTE selects each character of each string (from right to left), and

- `stringno` is a number suitable to group the characters of each string
- `string` is the string that is being reversed
- `charno` is the position of this character (and counts from `length()` down to 1)
- `char` is the character itself

Finally, `group_concat()` is used to re-assemble the individual characters, giving the desired result:

```
| Hello       | olleH       |
| world!      | !dlrow      |
| foo bar baz | zab rab oof |
```